# Python - how to use a sklearn classifier in webpage

Tags: scikit-learn, html

I am learning Python and I have a question. I have built a classifier (named as `build.py`) which is as follows:

```
file = 'file path/CVdb.csv'
input = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file,index_col=None,encoding='ISO-8859-
1',sep=',')
text = input.drop_duplicates()
corpus = text.Text.str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9+#,]+',' ')
category = text.Skill.str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9&,]+',' ')
stopset = list(set(stopwords.words('english')))
X_train = corpus
Y_train = category
classifier = Pipeline([ ('vectorizer',TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',stop_words=stopset,max_features=20 )),
('clf', linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',alpha=0.0001,penalty='elasticnet'))])
model = classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)
joblib.dump(model,'model.pkl')
```

This `model.pkl` is getting saved in the same file path that I have defined as `file`. Now I am using this model for further use as follows through running another .py file named as `deploy.py`:

```
file = 'D:/Arghya - Others/Python Work/OwL/Demo-1/CVdb-test.csv'
input = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file,index_col=None,encoding='ISO-8859-
1',sep=',')
text = input.drop_duplicates()
corpus = text.Text.str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9+#,]+',' ')
stopset = list(set(stopwords.words('english')))
vect_new = 
TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="word",max_features=20,stop_words=stopset)
X_Test = vect_new.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
predict_new = model.predict(corpus)

ds = pd.Series(predict_new)
output = ds.to_csv('filepath/output.csv',sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
```

So far so good!!
Now I want this `deploy.py` to be used in an webpage where through an  UI an user can input a file (which is a `.doc` or `.pdf` types) and click a button. Upon clicking, `deploy.py` would be called and perform the classification. 
How can I accomplish this.
I have python 3.5 version and running on Window 7 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a python web framework so you can use python code to run a website.  There are lots of options. Here are two popular ones:

1. Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/)
2. Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/)

I would probably start with flask. :)

Comment: Thanks!! But all I want that the scripts should run when a specific button is clicked. Webpages can be written  in php or html

Comment: What I want is to run the above scripts from a website. Hence I am not looking for flask per sey.

Comment: Your scripts need to run server-side using python. So yes, you can build your server-side with php or whatever but you'll need to call a python process from PHP.

Comment: to every one or anybody, can I use this through CGI? if so, can anybody help me here?